# need other eyes to look for my mistake. php to recieve GPS coordinates

Tags: php, sql

I'm new to php and I have a problem.  I'm working on a webpage to receive gps coordinates from an android app.  I'm getting an error about an SQL statement here is the code:

```
?php

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
    echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
} else {
    echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}


$usr = "bikemap";
  $pwd = "pedalhard";
  $db = "test";
  $host = "localhost";

  $cid = mysql_connect($host,$usr,$pwd);

  if (!$cid) { echo("ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "\n"); }

  $userID = $_POST['userID'];
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $time = $_POST['time'];

  $lat = $_POST['lat'];
  $long = $_POST['long'];
  $alt = $_POST['alt'];
   mysql_select_db("test");

  $SQL = " INSERT INTO gpsdata ";
$SQL = $SQL . " (userID, date, time, lat, long, alt) VALUES ";
$SQL = $SQL . " ('$userID', '$date', '$time', '$lat','$long','$alt') ";
$result = mysql_query("$SQL");

if (!$result) {
    echo("ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "\n$SQL\n"); }




mysql_close($cid); 
?>
```

Here is the error I recieved:

> ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'long, alt) VALUES ('', '', '', '','','')' at line 1 INSERT INTO
>   gpsdata (userID, date, time, lat, long, alt) VALUES ('', '', '',
>   '','','')

Comment: Please note that you have written a program vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please use [PHP PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to ensure you do not write programs with SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: ... or just use `mysql_real_escape_string()`. It's perfectly safe - although PDO makes escaping harder to forget. It's the more modern library and definitely worth a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long` is being parsed as a datatype, not a field name.

To fix this, put quotes around field names, as in:

```
$SQL = $SQL . " (`userID`, `date`, `time`, `lat`, `long`, `alt`) VALUES ";
```

Answer (score 2):

`LONG` is a [reserved word in mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Either wrap the field name in backticks:

```
$SQL = $SQL . " (`userID`, `date`, `time`, `lat`, `long`, `alt`) VALUES ";
```

or rename the field.

Also, your script is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You want to fix that before going live.

Comment: Fun fact: `INSENSITIVE` is a reserved word, too! Something to bear in mind when designing a table structure for a dating site.

Answer (score 0):

`long` is a reserved word in MySQL. Use `lon`, or quote it using ` characters.

Answer (score 0):

LONG is a reserved word in my SQL, you need to enclose it with backticks